# Out of database PostGIS rasters are displaying incorrectly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal

I've stored a series of rasters in PostgtreSQL/PostGIS, as out-of-databse rasters using the -R switch in GDAL. There is an error when these rasters are displayed in QGIS- the colours are either switched around, or all red hues, or entirely black, or sometimes the image is diagonally skewed.

I've tried variations of the GDAL switches to no avail. When the raster is loaded normally into QGIS from the file server (instead of via PostGIS), there are no errors. Thoughts?

Comment: Same problem here any solution yet?